# How can I find when HTML5 audio actually starts playing (onplay event does not seem to work anywhere)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio, html5-apps

I need to catch the exact moment when HTML5 audio starts producing sound.

It turns out not so simple as it seems.

You might expect audio starts playing when `onplay` or `onplaying` event is fired? No way. At least in WebKit family, it seems to be **no browser event** that fires exactly at this point of time. In Chrome, Safari and Firefox  `onplay` and `onplaying` events are just faking their behaviour by simply firing together with `oncanplay`!

I've prepared a simple test to prove that fact. It demonstrates that audio actually starts playing after some reasonable time (over 100ms - 400ms) when all the events had already been fired.

You can notice this by your ears and ears if you look at console log. In the log I output `currentTime` every 15ms. It seems to reflect the actual audio state correctly, and it starts changing 10-40 polls after any event has been fired. So the audio is still freezed after `play` is fired.

Test code looks like this:

```
    var audioEl = new Audio('http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg');

    audioEl.oncanplay = function () {
        console.log('oncanplay');

        audioEl.currentTime = 1;    

        console.log('ready state is: ' + audioEl.readyState);
        audioEl.play();
    }


    audioEl.oncanplay = function () {
        console.log('oncanplay again');
    }

    audioEl.onplay = function() {
        console.log('onplay -----------------');
    }

    audioEl.onplaying = function() {
        console.log('onplaying ----------------');
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        console.log(audioEl.currentTime);
    }, 15);
```

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnTWS/2/)

I critically need to know the exact moment when the audio starts playing for precise synchronisation with visual animations.

Of course, I can find this moment roughly using quick polling. This is very bad for performance in real-time app, especially on mobile.

I'm asking if anyone knows any better solution for this. HTML audio implementation looks to be still so poor in 2014 :(

Comment: Does the `onplaying` event not fulfill your requirements?  It triggers when the media is actually being played.

Comment: I don't think it has poor support.  It is HTML5 and on their compatibility list, it just shows mobile browsers, which android version 2.X.X is older and the [distribution](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net) of it isn't as great.  For [desktop](http://caniuse.com/audio) browsers, it is pretty well supported.

Answer (score 3):

As @justin says, you can listen for the `playing` event to get the (more or less) precise moment the media starts actually playing. But yeah I've been seeing some spotty support for media events and `readyState` in general, [even in latest Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73609).

Whether those events work or not, I advise against using `setInterval` for animation (or just about anything else, for that matter). Instead, use `requestAnimationFrame`, which will fire more often and should synchronize with the browser and video card's repaint. And you can poll for the `currentTime` value on every frame to calculate where you should be in your animation. Performance shouldn't be a problem; your case is *exactly* what `requestAnimationFrame` was designed for.

```
function update() {
    var currentTime = audioEl.currentTime;
    // update your animation here
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

While you're at it, don't set `currentTime` to 5 until after `readyState > 0` or the `loadedmetadata` event fires. If you try to set `currentTime` before the browser has loaded enough of the video file to know the duration, it will throw an error. But you can call `play()` whenever you want; it doesn't have to wait for `canplay`.

Comment: I have played with events and they seem not to work. You can check out my updated http://jsfiddle.net/LnTWS/3/.  After spending a day on research, I end up with polling using your advise, `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: Glad it's working out for you. But FYI, all the events in your jsfiddle work fine for me in Firefox and Chrome. Not in Safari. Try calling `audioEl.play()` immediately after you create the element.

Comment: @brianchris I have spent some time on trying my test fiddle on Webkit browsers among different OSes, and what I get everywhere is a time gap between `play` event and actually playing sound. This can be discovered visually by viewing the console log. The audio is still freezed after `play` is fired.

Comment: My problem is that I have a huge delay between firing the event and audio start. I hope I was clear )

Comment: It makes sense that there might be a delay between `play` and hearing sound. But you should hear something (and see `currentTime` increase) immediately after `playing`.

Comment: For me, the audio starts playing pretty much immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Try the canplaythrough instead. Might help and would be better to be sure your audio can  be palyed all the way to the end anyway..

```
audioEl.oncanplay = function () {
      console.log('ready state is: ' + audioEl.readyState);
      audioEl.play();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `oncanplay` if fired far before the moment when sound actually starts palying